# Where to find myths about the origin of civilization?

Tags: reference-request

Is there a particular book (from a trustworthy source of course) I can see/buy or website(s) (preferably academic, that legally allow(s) non-academics access to this information)?

Edit: Initially, I had in mind myths about ways through which humanity is taught civilization (e.g. a deity teaching humans laws, and how to live by laying the foundation of city-living in general) but I guess I'll also accept the additional information this question seems to ask for.

Comment: I've seen a few on Wikipedia (though they were not in detail), but I'm looking for more.

Comment: The ancient Greek stuff is almost all available online.  (I'll look to put together an answer at some point if no one beats me to it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions:

[The Structural Study of Myth (Levi-Strauss, 1955)](https://people.ucsc.edu/~ktellez/levi-strauss.pdf)

[Patterns in Comparative Folklore (Eliade, 1948)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/778574.Patterns_in_Comparative_Religion)

[Sacred Narrative: Readings in the Theory of Myth (University of California Press, 1984)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1520617.Sacred_Narrative)

[Creation Myths of the World (Encyclopedia, Two Volume)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7724944-creation-myths-of-the-world-2-volumes)